# async CTP AcceptTcpClientAsync method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcplistener

I'm experimenting with the C# async CTP library and a socket server. I'm trying to listen for connections using the extension method `AcceptTcpClientAsync` which is added onto the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` class. My code looks like this:

```
  ...
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ServerPort);
        listener.Start();

        while (_active)
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            AddConnection(client);
        }

        listener.Stop();

  ...
```

However, if I put a breakpoint at `AddConnection` it is never hit. Am I using this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks fine to me - you should get to the break point only when something tries to actually connect. Sounds like a silly question but - is anything connecting? If so, what happens when it tries?

Comment: Hmm, if I follow a breakpoint through the calling code it successfully opens a connection and sends it's data, but never gets a response. However when it opens it's connection the await statement in the above code isn't returning! If I replace that code with this https://gist.github.com/1127577 everything works fine. Very odd.

Comment: @Ceilingfish: What sort of application is this in? Console? WinForms? WPF? Can you post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's a Winforms application. I've made a sample application here: https://github.com/ceilingfish/AsyncBlockingTcpListenerBug

Comment: I experience the exact same thing. Im building the server in WPF(with gui) and lines after TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); is never hit by my breakpoint. Also, my server is closed, thus I cant make any connection. Have anybody found a solution?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, I've changed `await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();` to the `await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().Result;`. This solved the problem, but I don't really feel like blocking a pool's thread. I guess there should be another solution.

Comment: @Andrey-WD: Yes, but it's very hard to tell from just this information. (I certainly wouldn't add an answer like this these days.) I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].